# AWS certs on root domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have an AWS route 53 domain that's hosting an S3 bucket for my site. I added a wild card cert i.e. *.example.com to my domain.
However, when I access https://example.com the browser doesn't pick up the cert. If I go to to https://www.example.net the cert works just fine. (in both scenarios the page loads)

I'm wondering what the best solution would be? I see websites like facebook will automatically redirect to the 'www' subdomain but stackoverflow doesn't seem to?

Do I create a new cert?
Do I try to configure route 53 to automatically redirect? If so how? I see other people having this issue where they link to an s3 bucket but say it won't work over https?

SEO also seems to be something I should be considering but I'm not sure what the consequences would be specifically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need separate certificate for the root / naked domain.

SSL Certs are valid for the given wildcard depth. * , * .*, * .* .* etc.,

Based on the cert pattern you can notice it is

> *.example.com not *example.com

In case if it matches to all strings in the prefix without a dot. It will match all of the domains like

> aexample.com bexample.com and example.com

as well.

Also your cert works only to one level deep. It will not work for

anything.something.example.com

There is a nice discussion about the second level subdomain ssl certs.

https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain

Even in that case, you domain need to be only in the forms of,

something.anything.example.com and it will not work for something.example.com since cert is for

> such as  * .*.example.com  and not *.example.com

Hope it helps.

Comment: *"You need separate certificate"*  No, you don't.  You only need a separate *reference* to the bare domain in the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) of the wildcard certificate.  However, the reasons for this are as you indicate -- certificate wildcards match exactly one token to the left, not 0 and not more than 1.  It is also highly unlikely that a certificate can actually be obtained from a public CA for `*.*.example.com`.

Comment: I have experimented in depth with * .* .domains and *.domain and domain.  I have not been able to get it to work wthout a separate cert. Not seeing a clear answer from your comment as well.

Comment: Thanks @Kannaiyan I added a new cert to the root domain and added the wildcard cert as another domain name. Warning to anyone else doing this, it can take a long time for the changes to take effect. Even though your AWS console says everything is good it can take hours before you see it reflected in the browser.

Comment: Glad it helped. Awesome.

Answer (score 4):

I think you don't need redirection. You can request an ACM certificate with multiple domains [(use the "Add more names" button)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request.html)i.e. you have to request a new certificate for following domains:
Domain 1: example.com (for the apex domain itself)
Domain 2: *.example.com (for subdomains till one level)

Once it is issued and attached to supported resource (should be CloudFront in your configuration), the certificate will protect both example.com and www.example.com .

Comment: Worked well for me